# apache ftp client add new line at end of file while retrieving file

Tags: ftp, apache-commons

I'm using apache ftp client to download text file. My problem is that when I retrieve file  I always find a new line at end of file. This is my code:

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

    ftpClient.connect(ftpServer);
    ftpClient.login(ftpUser, ftpPassword);

    log.info("Connected to server " + ftpServer + ".");
    log.info(ftpClient.getReplyString());

    int reply = ftpClient.getReplyCode();

    if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
        ftpClient.disconnect();
        throw new Exception("error");
    }

    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    boolean result = ftpClient.retrieveFile(fileName, output);

    output.close();

    ftpClient.logout();

    if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
        try {
            ftpClient.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    log.info("Disconnected from " + ftpServer + ".");
```

Later I read file using:

```
String value = new String(output.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Let try:
`ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);`
it helps.